# Breakpoint hits Hashmap.put() a simple Hello World Program

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints

Program is simple：

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Now I set a breakpoint into function `put(K key, V value)` in HashMap.class

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
```

and then I start debugging the HelloWorld.class, it will run into the breakpoint in HashMap. It is strange to me that how it can run into `put()` in HashMap?
I tried HashMap, Hashtable and they are all the same.

Comment: Check function calls stack in debug view and you will see which function invokes put.

Comment: Strange but even i just checked now...i suppose while loading class...there must be some classes which calls HashMap...HahsMap was called before the call of System.out.println() method

Comment: my IDE is MyEclipse.

Comment: Under the hood, no Java program is simple. There's a great deal of mechanism involved in setting up the internal environment for any program.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the stack trace I obtained when reproducing your scenario.

When the application is started by Eclipse, *it does not simply enter the Main function*. Your class needs to be loaded into the JVM, before creating an instance. For that, a *Class Loader* will be used.

In your case, URLClassLoader has a member of URLClassPath type that *uses a HashMap object*.

[image]

Comment: If URLClassLoader uses a HashMap, how does it load HashMap.class?

Answer (score 9):

**It is because of the way Eclipse launches applications.**

Eclipse `LauncherHelper` class running the app (HelloWorld) invokes a `URLClassLoader`, and tons of other things. The URLClassLoader uses `HashMaps`, `HashTables`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already using a Debugger you should also able to see the frames which show where your `put` method was called. In IntelliJ it looks like this:

[image: frames]

As you can see here, the method was called when the JVM tries to load a certain class: here it is your `HelloWorld` class. It does that to call the `main` method in there.

Since the JVM has just started it needs to fill a certain `HashMap<String, URLClassPath.Loader> lmap` in the `sun.misc.URLClassPath` class. This map contains entries to used resources like used jar files (for example the jar files from the Java installation) or `.class` locations like your *"bin"* directory of your project.
It will then be used during the runtime of your application.

But a `Map` will also be used, then the JVM loads the "permissions" in `java.security.Permissions` which has `Map<Class<?>, PermissionCollection> permsMap`.

As you can see, the call of the `put` method has nothing to do with the content of your own application. It is just used to load basic stuff for the Java environment and the application runtime.

Btw: try to get familiar with your debugger, it will help you to understand why certain methods get called and which class/method performs that call.